# Joining Results Back to Original Pandas GeoDataFrame Results in More Rows

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join

I have two point geodataframes: gdf_1 & gdf_2, with gdf_1 being the original dataframe and gdf_2 being the results from the analysis of gdf_1.  Both frames have the same number of rows, same geometry column, but different number of columns.  I would like to join all the columns from gdf_2 back to gdf_1.

```
joined = gpd.sjoin(gdf_1, gdf_2)
```

When I do this the number of rows in joined is greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what type of data you're working with, but my guess at what's happening is that `sjoin` will join any two rows which have geometries which intersect each other, even if that intersection is very very small. A common form of very very small intersection is when two shapes share a boundary. So for example if the shapes in `gdf_1` and `gdf_2` were the continents shown here:

[image: Map of the world]

Each of `gdf_1` and `gdf_2` would have 7 rows. However, when you joined them, the row for Europe in `gdf_1` would intersect both the row for Europe in `gdf_2` and the row for Asia in `gdf_2`, leaving you with more than the original number of geometries in the result, since there would be one row with the info from Europe in `gdf_1` and `gdf_2` and one row with the info from Europe in `gdf_1` and from Asia in `gdf_1`.

To avoid this, I would suggest trying a non-spatial join to link your two data frames with pandas' base `join` or `merge` function.